# How to convert multiple nested JSON files into single CSV file using MATLAB?

Tags: json, matlab, csv

I have about 200 nested JSON files that I need to convert into single CSV file to be able to read the data in tabular format. I am looking for ways to use MATLAB to achieve this task.

Answer (score 1):

1. use `jsondecode` to read the JSON file within MATLAB (cf. [doc](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/jsondecode.html))
2. convert your data tree into a table
3. export the table with `writetable` to a CSV file (cf. [doc](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/writetable.htm))